# Comparing cells within separate areas in Excel

Tags: vba, excel

**Detailed explanation of my requirements:**

If you imagine an Excel worksheet, now assume that data is contained within two separate "groups" on the worksheet.

Lets say the first 'group1' is defined as the data in the following cells:

```
                             [D4, E4, F4,
                              D5, E5, F5,
                              D6, E6, F6]
```

The second "group", 'group2', is defined as another set of cells containing data:

```
                             [H4, I4, J4,
                              H5, I5, J5,
                              H6, I6, J6]
```

I want to loop through the selected areas and perform comparisons as follows;

```
                             Compare D4 with H4,
                             Compare E4 with I4,
                             Compare F4 with J4,
                             Compare D5 with H5,
                             Compare E5 with I5,
                             Compare .....
                             Compare F6 with J6
                             End
```

When a compare is made on each iteration, if the cell elements are equal then I want the background color of the cell to be white, if the cell elements are unequal I want the background color of the cell to be left unchanged

Any advice is greatly appreciated.

**See my code here**:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim rangeToUse As Range, cell1 As Range, cell2 As Range, i As Integer, 
j As Integer

Set rangeToUse = Selection

If Selection.Areas.Count <= 1 Then
   MsgBox "Please select more than one area for cell to cell comparsion."
Else
    rangeToUse.Interior.ColorIndex = 39
     For i = 1 To rangeToUse.Areas.Count
      For j = i To rangeToUse.Areas.Count
          If cell1.Cells(i, j).Value = cell2.Cells(i, j).Value Then
                  cell1.Interior.ColorIndex = 0
                  cell2.Interior.ColorIndex = 0
          End If
  Next j
Next i

End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Now it appears clearer. A few more questions: 1) Will you always have only two regions? 2) Will the regions (regardless of their count) always be of the same size?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the finished code. It works very well, so I hope it saves someone some time.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim rangeToUse As Range, cell1 As Range
Dim area() As Range
Dim n As Integer
Dim same As Boolean

Set rangeToUse = Selection
n = rangeToUse.Areas.Count

If (n <= 1) Then
    MsgBox "Please select more than one area for cell to cell comparison."
Else
    ReDim area(1 To n)
    rangeToUse.Interior.ColorIndex = 39
    For i = 1 To n
        Set area(i) = rangeToUse.Areas(i)
    Next i
    For j = 1 To area(1).Cells.Count
    same = True
    For i = 2 To UBound(area)
    If area(i).Cells(j).Value <> area(i - 1).Cells(j).Value Then same=False
    Next i
    If same = True Then
        For i = 1 To UBound(area)
            area(i).Cells(j).Interior.ColorIndex = 2
        Next i
    End If
Next j
End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You did not post any question, so I will make two guesses.

**Guess #1**:
You have many `Area`s, with different sizes, and you want to avoid formatting cells whose contents is duplicated anywhere among `Area`s.

You need two pairs of nested loops, instead of one. One pair traverses `Area`s. The other pair traverses `Cell`s within `Area`s.
Find below streamlined code.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim rangeToUse As Range, cell1 As Range, cell2 As Range, i As Integer, j As Integer
    Dim area1 As Range, area2 As Range
    Dim n As Integer

    Set rangeToUse = Selection
    n = rangeToUse.Areas.Count

    If (n <= 1) Then
        MsgBox "Please select more than one area for cell to cell comparison."
    Else
        rangeToUse.Interior.ColorIndex = 39
        For i = 1 To n
            Set area1 = rangeToUse.Areas(i)
            For j = (i+1) To n
                Set area2 = rangeToUse.Areas(j)
                For Each cell1 In area1.Cells
                    For Each cell2 In area2.Cells
                        If (cell1.Value = cell2.Value) Then
                            cell1.Interior.ColorIndex = 0
                            cell2.Interior.ColorIndex = 0
                        End If
                    Next cell2
                Next cell1
            Next j
        Next i
    End If

End Sub
```

**Guess #2**:
You have two `Area`s, with the same size, and you want to avoid formatting cells whose contents is duplicated, at equivalent locations.

You need one loop.
Find below streamlined code.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim rangeToUse As Range, cell1 As Range, cell2 As Range, i As Integer, j As Integer
    Dim area1 As Range, area2 As Range
    Dim nr As Integer, nc As Integer

    Set rangeToUse = Selection
    n = rangeToUse.Areas.Count

    If (n <= 1) Then
        MsgBox "Please select more than one area for cell to cell comparison."
    Else
        rangeToUse.Interior.ColorIndex = 39
        Set area1 = rangeToUse.Areas(1)
        Set area2 = rangeToUse.Areas(2)
        nr = area1.Rows.Count
        nc = area1.Columns.Count
        For i = 1 To nr
            For j = 1 To nc
                Set cell1 = area1.Cells(i,j)
                Set cell2 = area2.Cells(i,j)
                If (cell1.Value = cell2.Value) Then
                    cell1.Interior.ColorIndex = 0
                    cell2.Interior.ColorIndex = 0
                End If
            Next j
        Next i
    End If

End Sub
```

PS: I do not have a system to test it. You may have to fine tune it.

PS2: Code might perhaps be optimized in terms of speed, but if you do not see any performance issues, you would be ok with it.

Comment: Thanks Sancho.s, performance is not a major issue at the moment as the ranges of data I am comparing are relatively small. I tested the code and it works for the most part but it fails sometimes by finding elements from non-corresponding cells and matching them. Is there any way that I can do the following: Compare purely on a cell by cell basis?

Comment: @user4225083 - Great. Please note `For j = (i+1) To n` instead of `For j = i To n`. And please post feedback.

Comment: Ok, I just did a "Step Into" with the debugger. The problem with the code is that it selects the first cell in 'area1' and then compares it with all the cells in 'area2' before moving onto the next cell in 'area1' and comparing this against all the cells in 'area2' and so on until the end. What I need is to compare the corresponding cells one at a time. Any ideas?

Comment: @user4225083 - As said, I guessed what you wanted to do, and that is what I poured in the code. I am still not clear. It would help if you post sample images with the intended output, or an alternative showing a concrete example.

Comment: Sancho.s please take a look at my original problem statement at the top of this page, I have edited it so that it is a clearer indication of what I am trying to do (I hope), let me know if something is not clear to you. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so here is where I am at (See code below):

From running the debugger I have ascertained that the problem I need to eradicate exists between line 20 and line 29.

With the original code kindly provided by sancho.s (see above) I was comparing a cell in 'area1' with all the cells in 'area2', this was not good enough since as the loop progressed through 'area2' it could find multiple comparisons and change the ColorIndex in multiple cells, I do not want this.

I simply want to compare the values in corresponding cells (assuming square selection).

To counteract this I included the 'Exit For' on line 25 but this leads to a reverse of the original problem as 'Cell2' on line 28 does not increment.

Basically I need a way for 'Cell2' to map the location/position of 'Cell1' to enable like for like comparsion

```
1.)Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
2.)
3.)Dim rangeToUse As Range, cell1 As Range, cell2 As Range, i As Integer, 
4.)j As Integer
5.)Dim area1 As Range, area2 As Range
6.)Dim n As Integer
7.)
8.)Set rangeToUse = Selection
9.)n = rangeToUse.Areas.Count
10.)
11.)If (n <= 1) Then
12.)    MsgBox "Please select more than one area for cell to 
13.)            cell comparison."
14.) Else
15.)    rangeToUse.Interior.ColorIndex = 39
16.)For i = 1 To n
17.)        Set area1 = rangeToUse.Areas(i)
18.)        For j = (i + 1) To n
19.)           Set area2 = rangeToUse.Areas(j)
20.)            For Each cell1 In area1.Cells
21.)                For Each cell2 In area2.Cells
22.)                    If (cell1.Value = cell2.Value) Then
23.)                        cell1.Interior.ColorIndex = 0
24.)                        cell2.Interior.ColorIndex = 0
25.)                        Exit For
26.)                    End If
27.)                    
28.)                Next cell2
29.)            Next cell1
30.)        Next j
31.)    Next i
32.)End If

33.)End Sub
```